# javascript map function not adding to array as expected

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't the 'values' array contain the 'Title' of each item within 'results'?

The following code outputs: `1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3` rather than the desired: `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3`.

```js
var results = [
  {Title: '1'},
  {Title: '2'},
  {Title: '3'},
];
var fields = {
    Title: { Name:"Title", Required:true},
    Description: { Name:"Description", Required:false}
};
var values = [];
results.map(function(result, i){
    values[i] = fields;
    Object.keys(result).map(function(key, index) {
        values[i][key].Value = result[key];
    });
    console.log(values[i].Title.Value);
});
values.map(function(value){console.log(value.Title.Value)});
```

Comment: why map if you are not using the result of it?

Comment: I think you are mixing up *map* and *forEach* here...

Comment: Because you have a reference to the object, not a copy of it.

Comment: what are you trying do here - values.map(function(value){console.log(value.Title.Value)}); ?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well, in literal notation.

Answer (score 0):

Map function doesn't transform the current array you are working with it returns a new one with the altered data, and also you are starting values as an empty array you have to push the new values.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var results = [
  {Title: '1'},
  {Title: '2'},
  {Title: '3'},
 ];
 var fields = {
    Title: { Name:"Title", Required:true},
    Description: { Name:"Description", Required:false}
 };
 var values = [];
 values =  results.map(function(result, i){
    values[i] = fields;
    Object.keys(result).map(function(key, index) {
        values[i][key].Value = result[key];
    });
    console.log(values[i].Title.Value);
  });
```

The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element.

The map() method calls the provided function once for each element in an array, in order.

Note: map() does not execute the function for array elements without values.

Note: map() does not change the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick with reduce and map over the fields using a reduce function for simplicity.

```js
var rawData = [
  { Title: '1' },
  { Title: '2' },
  { Title: '3' },
]
var fieldInfo = {
  Title       : { Name:"Title",       Required: true  },
  Description : { Name:"Description", Required: false }
}
var result = transformData(rawData, fieldInfo)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))

result.forEach(item => console.log('Value: ', item.Title.Value))

function transformData(data, fields) {
  return data.map((record, i) => {
    return Object.keys(fields).reduce((result, key, index) => {
      result[key] = { Value : record[key] || null };
      // -- Begin field cloning.
      Object.keys(fields[key]).forEach(prop => result[key][prop] = fields[key][prop]);
      // -- End field cloning.
      return result
    }, {})
  })
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks, but why can't I change `result[key] = { Value : record[key] }` to `result[key] = fields[key];result[key].Value = record[key];`?

Comment: @user247298 I added support for cloning field data. You never want to set a reference to an object if you are using it more than once. Just loop over the object you want to copy and clone its properties.

Comment: Thanks @mr-polywirl. What if I want to include fields with no values in the object that gets returned for each result ie. Description? I'd actually like the Value property set to "" rather than undefined in these fields.

Comment: @user247298 I grabbed the keys off of the fields rather than the record. Run the code again.